# Add Microsoft Access to my 2010 package

Tags: microsoft-access-2010

Let me know if I am sinful for asking this and I will delete it.

I would like to add Access to my 2010 Office package (for a few months). Is that possible? How is it possible? The issue is that I am finishing a project that uses Access and I am moving away and need the application for loose ends. Should I export the data to some other format or just steal a 2010 package?

Comment: Can you use other database? Export access database into MySQL or MSSQL? You can get MSSQL 2012 Express for free directly from Microsoft...

Comment: Any more ideas?

Comment: If you're a student, and you are enrolled in university, you can search MSDNAA to see if your institution has MSDNAA subscription or not. If they have, that is a bunch of free software for academic / research / study purposes. Not for commercial purposes.

Comment: Your only choice is to purchase a license yourself. We cannot and will not help you with any other solutions that does not involve you purchasing a license. Feel free to use other software alternative.  We cannot advise you to "steal" anything.  You can either purchase a license or export it to another format.

Comment: So the question may be: Can I purchase a stand alone Access 2010 and add to the existing package?